# Pattern Matching Array of Bytes

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-collections

This fails to compile:

```
Array[Byte](...) match { case Array(0xFE.toByte, 0xFF.toByte, tail @ _* ) => tail }
```

I can, however, compile this:

```
val FE = 0xFE.toByte
val FF = 0xFF.toByte 
bytes match { Array( FE, FF, tail @ _* ) => tail }
```

Why does the first case fail to compile but not the second case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matching as currently implemented in Scala does not allow you to generate expressions inside your match statement: you must *either* have an expression *or* a match, but not both.

So, if you assign the values before you get into the match, all you have is a stable identifier, and the match works.  But unlike almost everywhere else in Scala, you *can't* substitute an expression like `0xFE.toByte` for the val `FE`.

Type inference will work, so you could have written

```
xs match { case Array(-2, -1, tail) => tail }
```

since it knows from the type of `xs` that the literals `-2` and `-1` must be Byte values.  But, otherwise, you often have to do just what you did: construct what you want to match to, and assign them to vals starting with an upper-case letter, and then use them in the match.

There is no exceedingly good reason why it *must* have been this way (though one does have to solve the problem of when to do variable assignment and when to test for equality and when to do another level of unapply), but this is the way it (presently) is.

Answer (score -1):

Because what you see in the `match` is not a constructor but `extractor`. Extractors extracts data into variables provided. That is why the second case works - you provide variables there. By the way, you did not have to create them in advance.

More about extractors at http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html

Comment: You're forgetting the upper/lower case thing.  It's not extracting data in this case.

Comment: Could you explain what is 'upper/lower case thing'?

Comment: `match { case (X, y) => ??? }` will pick out a tuple whose first element matches the pre-existing value of `X`, and bind the second element to `y`.  In general, if the first letter is a capital, the name is considered to be something to test against, while if it is lower case, it's a new variable name to bind the value to.